# Does increasing the number of stretched elastic bands increase the total elastic potential energy?

Tags: energy, elasticity

Suppose I stretch a single elastic band to $x$ cm attached to an object like a paperclip. The elastic has potential energy modelled by $$U = \frac{1}{2}kx^2$$ where $U$ is potential energy, $k$ is the Spring Force Constant, and $x$ is the stretch length. Now suppose I stretch 2 elastic bands to $x$ cm. Now each elastic band has the same elastic potential energy, but does adding two elastic bands increase the speed of the paperclip when it is released? One would naturally assume that increasing the number of elastic bands will increase the speed the object is released at. However, I don't see that mathematically. Is it simply the sum of the potential energy of the two elastic bands? Or will the speed which the paperclip is released at remain the same regardless of the number of elastic bands?

Comment: Imagine the paper clip is a bowling ball, and imagine that the cases you wish to compare are 1 elastic band vs 100 elastic bands rather than 1 vs 2.

Comment: @Ben51 That certainly helps . However, how is this modelled mathematically?

Comment: Assuming the mass of the paper clip is much larger than the mass of the elastic bands, you can just add the energies as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to [series and parallel springs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_springs).

Your situation of multiple springs can be modeled with the equation of 1 spring (if you're willing to assume that the paperclip acts as a point mass and there's no rotation involved, and also each spring is stretched by the same distance).

The overall motion of your paperclip is described by $m\ddot x = -k_\mathrm{eq}x$ where $k_\mathrm{eq}=k_1+k_2+k_3+\cdots$, and $k_i$ denotes the spring constant of the $i$-th spring. That is, the equivalent spring constant $k_\mathrm{eq}$ is the sum of the spring constants of each of the springs.

This can be shown as follows:

The net force $m\ddot x$ equals the sum of forces each spring provides. Provided that each spring is stretched the same distance $x$. Therefore,

$$m\ddot x = -k_1 x-k_2 x +\cdots\qquad \implies\qquad m\ddot x = - (k_1+k_2+\cdots) x$$

From there, you can get the equation of motion and also show that the energies corresponding to each spring add up. Of course, as pointed out in the comments, you would be assuming that the elastics have negligible mass.